# Who is doing the action?

Tags: grammar

「迷宮都市オラリオ。「ダンジョン」と通称される地下迷宮を保有する。いや迷宮の上に築き上げられた巨大都市。**都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する「ギルド」を中核して栄える都市は**、ヒューマン含めあらゆる種族の亜人が生活を営んでいる。」

How can you figure out who is doing the action of ギルドを中核にする?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parse it as:

> [(都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する)「ギルド」を中核にして栄える]都市

都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する「ギルド」を中核にして栄える is a relative clause modifying 都市.
都市 is the subject for the action 都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する「ギルド」を中核にして栄える.

(Likewise, 都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する is the relative clause modifying ギルド, and ギルド is the subject for 都市、ひいてはダンジョンを管理する.)

Comment: ギルドを中核にして means ギルドを中心にして, with the Guild at the core.